# Finding files containing occurrences of a string

Tags: shell, unix, grep

One of my tasks is to count the number of files that match a certain date pattern. Really what I need to do is loop through the directory, examine each file name, find the 2nd period in that file name, and then examine the next 4 characters to see if there is a match on the date string I am assembling.

November of 2012 would be represented as "1211".  Using the first four characters after the 2nd period in the file names below, this would give us a hit on the first file name ("o.tt.121113150804") since it matches that pattern. I would count that file and then leave the other two alone.

The files below are just a sampling.  They can be named in many different ways.  They usually are just variations of the below 99% of the time.  The fact that there are 2 periods and I need to check the 4 digits after the 2nd one is a definite constant though.

File names I need to check:

```
o.tt.121113150804
o.stpw.101209092541
i.rtat.120831045704
```

Comment: How is that a bash question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with `ls` alone but this will also match directories:

```
$ ls
i.rtat.120831045704  o.stpw.101209092541  o.tt.121113150804

$ ls *.*.1121*
o.tt.121113150804
```

However `find` is more powerful and flexible:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.*.1211*"
./o.tt.121113150804
```

Options:

`-maxdepth 1` only look in this directory.

`-type f` only find files, not directories.

`-iname` use pattern to match file name where `*` matches anything so `*.*.1211*` matches anything followed by `.` followed by anything followed by a second `.` followed by your date string and `*` anything else.

**Edit:**

To count to number of matches you could pipe to `wc -l` and use command substitution `$(...)` to store the value in a variable:

```
$ ls
i.rtat.120831045704  o.stpw.101209092541  o.tt.121113150804  
o.tt.121113150804c1  o.tt.121113150804c2

$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.*.1211*" | wc -l
3

$ found=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.*.1211*" | wc -l)

$ echo $found
3
```

Comment: There is might a minor issue, this seems to be detecting file names with single dot in the name like `a.12111231`, the op seems to be looking for files second `.`. This `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.*.1211*"` seems be working. Please have a look

Comment: @another.anon.coward good point, don't think case sensitivity is required here so `-name` would suffice but I left it in just in case. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Whatever flavor of shell we have doesn't like maxdepth or iname.  But I can work around that.  This is working great.  I do thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem, for future reference make sure to do `man find` to see what options you do have they may be slightly different.

Comment: Will do.  On the offhand you see this again...would you know how to properly count these results?  So that if the find command found 5 instances it could put that in a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Note that the pattern `*.*.1211*` will match files with *more than two dots* before the fixed string. For example, `a.b.c.1211` will match.

With bash you can write:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls  +([^.]).+([^.]).1211*
```

If you just want to count them:

```
files=( +([^.]).+([^.]).1211* )
echo "${#files[@]} files matched"
```

Answer (score 0):

@sudo_O and @glennjackman answered your question but as an alternative if you wanted to get counts for all dates at once you could do

```
ls | awk -F'.' '{count[substr($3,1,4)]++} END{for (date in count) print date, count[date]}'
```